# jQuery Datepicker okay on first load of a page but fails thereafter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

This is the second time I have asked this question.  Neither the responses I received initially nor any of the myriad of other answers to similar questions have helped me to solve the problem.

The problem is that once a datepicker object is initialized, a second initialization causes it to fail.  I have tried all sorts of blurring and destroying but nothing has worked for me.

Please take a look at [this simple page which demonstrates the problem](http://www.dmdefd.com/testing/divtest.html)

Here is the javascript for the page that contains the datepicker input elements...

```
$(document).ready (function(){
     sp = " ";
     lf = '\n'


  $(function (){
     $("input#datepicker").datepicker(); 
     $("input#datepicker2").datepicker();   
  })


})// document ready
```

I would truly appreciate any help to get this working.  I've already spent about eight hours with no success.

Thanks,

-dmd-

Comment: jQueryUI (and many other UI libraries) attach a lot of "stuff" to elements, and removing the element from the DOM by overwirting the div's contents doesn't get rid of it.  Have you tried calling [destroy](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-destroy) before load?

Comment: Could you please explain how to destroy the datepicker object?

Comment: "destroy" above is a hyperlink to the docs (SO has some pretty bad contrast issues IMHO and it's hard to see) but it's `$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "destroy" );`

Comment: Yes, that's the syntax I have tried.  Unfortunately, it does not solve the problem.

`$('input#datepicker').datepicker ("destroy"); 

 $("input#datepicker").datepicker(); 

 $('input#datepicker2').datepicker ("destroy"); 
 $("input#datepicker2").datepicker();`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is obsolete. you got a document ready function inside of an document ready function ( `$(function(){})` is a shorthand of `$(document).ready(function(){})`. But this isn't the Problem. Use the following code in your divtest.html and remove the calls in datepicker.html:

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('DOMNodeInserted','input#datepicker,input#datepicker2', function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I have tried this but now the datepicker elements do not show at all.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have a solution and it is simple.

On the datepicker page, before initializing datepicker, add this line

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div').remove();
```

then

```
$("input#datepicker").datepicker(); 
$("input#datepicker2").datepicker();
```

This works for me and I truly hope it works for everyone else who has been bogged down with the issue.